# UIWebView - NSStringWithFormat

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to get a UIWebView working with the following code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",recipe.name];
```

`recipe.name` is the entity and property from the core data model

I used NSLog to test the `recipe.name` and it is outputting correctly to the console

I tried this with just a plain URL and it works fine:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/soup"];
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what is going wrong?

Comment: I have a database table w/ recipe names that I want to append onto a wikipedia url to display in a UIWebView. each recipe name can be called using 'recipe.name'
if I use the following it works fine: NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/soup"]; 

however, if I try to put append an object on to the end of the URL like this:
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",recipe.name];

it doesn't load the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initialize your `UIWebView`.
2. Create an `NSURL-object` containing your url(using +`[NSURL URLWithString:]` for example).
3. Create an `NSURLRequest-object` with the created `NSURL-object`.
4. load the `NSURLRequest` in your webView.
5. Voila

   :)

Comment: I had done that, and the code works like this:

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/soup"];            
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

it doesn't work w/ the recipe.name object:

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@",recipe.name];              
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];   
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: U'll ned to encode the urlstring. as such:

NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString: [urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: thanks so much for your replies.

is that because there's a space in the 'recipe.name' - like "Club Sandwich" ?

Comment: No worries! =)
It's to avoid any character that might not work well in a URL, space being one of them.

Comment: it's working now! that's a good bit of code to know.

thanks again.